# Binding based on custom annotation

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm new to both stackoverflow and guice.  I'm not sure what I'm trying to do is possible with guice, but I sure hope it is.

My problem domain is that I'm trying to write a document reading system.  I have defined an interface for a DocumentReader.

```
public interface DocumentReader {
    MetaData readDocument() throws Exception
}
```

I have also defined a enumeration defining supported file types (i.e. extensions).

```
public enum FileType {
    doc,
    png,
    txt,
}
```

I have an implementation for each FileType, providing details of how to parse that file type.

```
public class MSWordReaderImpl implements DocumentReader {
    // ....
}

public class PlainTextReaderImpl implements DocumentReader {
    // ....
}
```

At this point, I have successfully written & tested a module that uses MapBinder & FactoryModuleProvider to inject each of these objects.  Each DocumentReader implementation that exists is individually added to the MapBinder.  What I'm hoping is that as additional implementations of DocumentReader are written, I could simply annotate them with which FileType(s) they support, and GUICE would be able to read the annotation and add them to the MapBinder appropriately (without me having to update the module per addition).  What I've envisioned is something like this:

```
@SupportedFileTypes( filetypes={ doc, docx } )
public class MSWordReaderImpl implements DocumentReader {
    // ....
}

@SupportedFileTypes( filetypes={txt} )
public class PlainTextReaderImpl implements DocumentReader {
    // ....
}
```

I've read through the GUICE documentation several times, but I'm just not seeing a way to accomplish this (if it is even possible!).  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your module scan the package(s) the classes will go in using reflection, looking for classes that implement `DocumentReader` and are annotated with `@SupportedFileTypes`. When it finds one, add it to the `MapBinder` for each file type.

If you don't want to scan the classpath, you could still simplify this for yourself by writing a method like this:

```
private void bindDocumentReaders(Class<? extends DocumentReader>... types) {
  for (Class<? extends DocumentReader> type : types) {
    FileType[] supportedFileTypes = type.getAnnotation(SupportedFileTypes.class)
        .filetypes();
    // add to MapBinder for each file type
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the solution I've been considering.  I just wasn't sure if it was something that GUICE handled out of the box.  From what I read in the documentation, the GUICE modules are intended to be lightweight (and won't even let you throw exception(s)).  Scanning the classpath doesn't seem light weight to me, but perhaps my options are limited.

Comment: @Zildijan85: Guice modules can really be as lightweight or not as you want. Often they'll just be simple bindings and very lightweight, but in some cases you may want them to read files or whatever else. Guice doesn't provide any out of the box support for classpath scanning though, as it generally prefers that you make things more explicit.

Comment: I believe this approach will work for my purpose.  My motivation is to create a plugin system that would enable a third party to write custom readers.  I'd like it so that the third party need only to implement DocumentReader and annotate their implementation with @SupportedFileTypes( {x,y,z} ).  I'm leaning towards placing something similar to your solution into a DocumentReaderDiscovertyService.  The DocumentReader GUICE module would invoke this service to find all implementations.  The discovery service may use config or another mechanism to allow third parties to identify their work.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to see how this works is to look at the source for the [Named](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/trunk/core/src/com/google/inject/name/Named.java) and [Names](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/trunk/core/src/com/google/inject/name/Names.java) class, and how it is [used](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations).

First create a RequiredFileType annotation,

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD })
@BindingAnnotation
public @interface RequiredFileType {
  FileType value();
}
```

Then annotate the class which depends on Document reader like,

```
@Inject
ServiceRequiringWordReader(@RequiredFileType(doc) DocumentReader reader)
```

Then create a RequiredFileTypes utility which is equivalent to Names (code ommitted), and in your module write code like,

```
bind(DocumentReader.class)
    .annotatedWith(RequiredFileTypes.for(doc))
    .to(MSWordReaderImpl.class);
bind(DocumentReader.class)
    .annotatedWith(RequiredFileTypes.for(docx))
    .to(MSWordReaderImpl.class);
bind(DocumentReader.class)
    .annotatedWith(RequiredFileTypes.for(txt))
    .to(PlainTextReaderImpl.class);
```

Comment: I will have to take a look at the Named & Names utilities to see if they have any gems in them.  Your answer is helpful, but I'm not sure it satisfies what I was looking for.  ServiceRequiringWordReader requires you to know about all supported file types in the constructor.  I would like for MSWordReaderImpl to be annotated with the filetypes it supports, and for that to be the only place a FileType is associated.  I think in your solution, I would have to update ServiceRequiringWordReader everytime a new implementation is created.